# return object from firestore db instead of promise inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I'm trying to access the data inside of my user object in my firestore databases. However, I keep getting promises instead of the objects.

```
function StorefrontPage(props) {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const uid = auth.user && auth.user.uid;


  useEffect(() => { uid && getUser(uid, setUser);
  console.log(user);
  }, [])

  console.log(user);
```

The first time I run this, it returns the objects I want, but subsequent refreshes and page changes will turn the console.log into a **proto** object/promise. I thought wrapping it inside of the useEffect hook would solve this issue, but it is not. How do I make sure it always returns the user object instead of a promise?

For reference, the getUser function is:

```
export function getUser2(uid, setUser) {
  return firestore.collection('users')
                 .doc(uid).get()
                 .then(user => setUser(user))
                 .catch(err => console.log(err));        
}
```

Comment: This is expected.  `then` and `catch` both return promises the resolves when the entire chain of promises resolves.

Comment: @DougStevenson how do i get it to return the object instead of promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)